# "Are any classes taught on..." or "Is any class taught on..."

Tags: grammatical-number

Should I say: "Are any classes taught on Wednesdays?"

Or should I instead say "Is any class taught on Wednesdays?"

Which one is correct/more appropriate?

Comment: Why use _any_ at all? _Are classes taught on Wednesdays?_ does the job without implication or anxiety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both grammatically correct, but can have different meanings. The first one (Are there any classes taught on Wednesdays?) could be used within the context of, say, trying to find a class to fill a gap in your schedule on Wednesdays. So the answers you could expect to get are:

1) Yes, we have PHYS101 and PHYS400 taught on Wednesdays from 12p-1p.

2) No, there are no classes available on Wednesdays.

The second one (Is any class taught on Wednesdays?) can have the same meaning as above, but could also mean, "Is class held on Wednesdays?" Possible answers to this would be:
1) Yes, there is class on Wednesdays.

2) No, there is no class on Wednsdays.

---

As John Lawler mentioned, the "any" provides a degree of implication, in that you want specifics in the answer provided. If you drop the "any," then the question becomes a simple yes/no question. I don't know about adding anxiety, though.